# Cannot run GAP in cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, terminal, shell, cygwin

I've got [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) which I would like to run from inside emacs. There is something called gap mode for emacs which I installed. It obviously finds the correct executable to run GAP since it starts with the GAP initialization messages

```
 ┌───────┐   GAP 4.8.10, 15-Jan-2018, build of 2018-01-15 14:36:25 (GMTST)
 │  GAP  │   https://www.gap-system.org
 └───────┘   Architecture: i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-default32
 Libs used:  gmp, readline
 Loading the library and packages ...
```

However immediately after that it says

```
Error opening terminal: dumb.
```

and stops.

Subsequently I discovered that exactly the same happens if I run the GAP default starting script from the cygwin shell.

GAP also comes with batch files to run it in various ways on Windows, including its own version of rxvt; for that one, it sets `TERMINFO` environment variable pointing to a GAP folder with some terminal-related stuff. I tried to do `export TERMINFO=`(the same folder) or (the cygwin terminfo folder) in the cygwin shell before calling GAP, but the result was again exactly the same.

Mine is Windows 10, with the most recent cygwin64.

Can anybody advise what to do?

Comment: `cygwin64` is not `i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-default32` so there is a mismatch in architecture. There is a GAP 64bit ?

Comment: @matzeri They have an experimental x64 version but unfortunately it has its own problems. Do you believe the reason might be architecture incompatibility?

Comment: Likely. GAP is surely using its own 32bit cygwin1.dll, that is different from the 64bit cygwin1.dll of the cygwin installation.